# Understanding Scroll Anchoring Behavoir

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have the following very simple page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
        <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
                <style>
                        div {height : 1500px}
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="top" style='background-color: #ec8686;' >
                        <h1>TOP DIV</h1>     
                </div>

                <div id="middle" style='background-color: #95eb95;' >
                        <h1>MIDDLE DIV</h1>
                        <input type="button" value="Hide Top" onclick="document.getElementById('top').remove();">  
                        <input type="button" value="Hide Bottom" onclick="document.getElementById('bottom').remove();">  
                </div>

                <div id="bottom" style='background-color: #a9a9f5;' >
                        <h1>BOTTOM DIV</h1>     
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

On desktop, if I click on "hide top" or "hide bottom", the scroll bar is automatically adjusted by the browser such that the buttons remain in view as expected by the scroll anchoring feature.

On mobile however (Chrome and Safari iOS), only "Hide Bottom" maintains scroll anchoring. "Hide Top" causes content jumps.

Why is that? Is this a bug in mobile implementation? Any proper fix? I am trying to keep the buttons in view and avoid jumps regardless whether content is added or removed at the top or bottom.

This is JSFIDDLE for your convenience. Try it on mobile to see the issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/zb31a9m0/